# Input field not erasing React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, user-input

I'm learning React and I created a simple todo list app and I'm trying to erase the input field as I did for my onClick function on my keypress function. However, it doesn't render the same when I use  `setTodoInput("");` on that keypress function. It only shows the first character of the input. If I comment out  `setTodoInput("");` out of the keypress function, it works fine, but the input field doesn't erase. I don't understand why although I have a controlled input, it doesn't function the same. if someone can please explain, it would be appreciated.

this is my code for my App file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputArea from "./InputArea";
import ToDoTask from "./ToDoTask";

function App() {
  const [todoTasks, setTodoTasks] = useState([]);

  function addTask(todoInput) {
    setTodoTasks((prevTodoTasks) => {
      return [...prevTodoTasks, todoInput];
    });
  }

  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setTodoTasks((prevTodoInput) => {
        const newTodoInput = event.target.value;
        return [...prevTodoInput, newTodoInput];
      });
      // const newTodoInput = event.target.value;
      //   setTodoTasks((prevTodoTasks) => {
      //     console.log(newTodoInput);
      //     return [...prevTodoTasks, newTodoInput];
      //   });
      // }
    }
  }

  function deleteTodoTask(id) {
    setTodoTasks((prevTodoTasks) => {
      return prevTodoTasks.filter((task, i) => {
        return i !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <InputArea onAdd={addTask} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {todoTasks.map((todoTasks, i) => (
            <ToDoTask
              key={i}
              id={i}
              text={todoTasks}
              onChecked={deleteTodoTask}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also created an input component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function InputArea(props) {
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    const newInput = event.target.value;
    setTodoInput(newInput);
  }

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <input
        onKeyDown={(event) => {
          props.onKeyPress(event);
          setTodoInput("");
        }}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        value={todoInput}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.onAdd(todoInput);
          setTodoInput("");
        }}
      >
        <span>Add</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputArea;
```

this is my todoTask component:

```
import React from "react";

function ToDoTask(props) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        props.onChecked(props.id);
      }}
    >
      <li>{props.text}</li>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDoTask;
```

Comment: I do not see the purpose of erasing an input while pressing any key on that input. But if you want to understand what you did: Actually you override the value by setting `setTodoInput("");` but the key pressed will also be triggered

Comment: Why are you trying to simultaneously `setTodoInput(newInput);` and `setTodoInput("");` on the input? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: The goal I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to erase the input field once I press enter and transfer it over as a task like I did for my onClick function. However, when I try to do it with my keyPress function, the input still displays after I press "Enter".

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to clear the input when "enter" is pressed then I suggest using a form element. So long as there is just the one input then pressing enter while focused will submit the form. Use the form's submit handler to call the `onAdd` callback and reset the local `todoInput` state.

InputArea

```
function InputArea({ onAdd }) {
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todoInput) {
      onAdd(todoInput);
      setTodoInput("");
    }
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setTodoInput(value);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={todoInput} />
      <button type="submit">
        <span>Add</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

### Demo

```js
function InputArea({ onAdd }) {
  const [todoInput, setTodoInput] = React.useState("");

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todoInput) {
      onAdd(todoInput);
      setTodoInput("");
    }
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setTodoInput(value);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={todoInput} />
      <button type="submit">
        <span>Add</span>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

function ToDoTask(props) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        props.onChecked(props.id);
      }}
    >
      <li>{props.text}</li>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [todoTasks, setTodoTasks] = React.useState([]);

  function addTask(todoInput) {
    setTodoTasks((prevTodoTasks) => {
      return [...prevTodoTasks, todoInput];
    });
  }

  function deleteTodoTask(id) {
    setTodoTasks((prevTodoTasks) => {
      return prevTodoTasks.filter((task, i) => {
        return i !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <InputArea onAdd={addTask} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {todoTasks.map((todoTasks, i) => (
            <ToDoTask
              key={i}
              id={i}
              text={todoTasks}
              onChecked={deleteTodoTask}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```